# How convert array byte little endian to big endian?

Tags: java

Do you have an idea to pass this UnitTest?

```
@Test public void convert() {   
    byte[] num = {1,0,0,0};//little endian  
    byte[] answer = {0,0,0,1};//big endian  
    assertArrayEquals(answer , Convert.converting(num)); 
}

public static byte[] converting(byte[] value) {
    //TO DO     
    /* ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(nombre); // Not working
    bb.order( ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return bb; */
}
```

Comment: Does you somehow think a `ByteBuffer` can be converted to a `byte[]` implicitly?

Comment: Could you give more example inputs with desired outputs? I mean if you just want to pass the test, you could just `return new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 };` but that wouldn't really be what you want, would it?

Comment: My goal is to be able to convert a byte array into a big endian and transform it into a hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invert the `byte[]` array yourself by changing the convert method to:

```
public static byte[] converting(byte[] value) {
    final int length = value.length;
    byte[] res = new byte[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        res[length - i - 1] = value[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You could consider to accept one of the answers on this question, if they  proved to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` that does not change 'internal' representation of the ByteBuffer. It just allows you to get from it integers/long etc in correct endian representation (as you need to have multibyte type to have meaningfull endianness).

Comment: Oh, I did not know it. Thanks.

Comment: TBH I really _wish_ ByteBuffer _did_ support a method that did exactly what one would expect. For example, I wish ByteBuffer had a `asOrderedBytes()` method or similar that would swap on-the-fly based on the currently set byte order.